# Creation of VMS within AWS Ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtualization

I am trying to design and making architecture of cloud application deployment resources in AWS cloud using EC2, S3, and RDS. Here I have a little bit of confusion about AWS infrastructure, which I am describing here.

I already have a AWS EC2 machine - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Is possible to create another VMs within my Ubuntu? I mean, can I use Linux or CentOS within my EC2 Ubuntu machine?

I am a beginner in cloud and AWS world, still exploring about AWS infrastructure.

Comment: Each AWS EC2 instance is a Virtual machine(VM)  themselves. Those  defacto choices of OS  image (AMI) is there to help user to deploy OS ASAP.  Since AWS is an VM instance, it let you upload your own VM : https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/.  Nevertheless, you must make sure the VM image compliance with the specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instantiate your EC2 instance you are required to select an AMI. the AMI is an amazon machine image. This essentially describes what OS (CentOS, Ubuntu, RedHat, etc) will be installed on your EC2 instance. Most likely you selected the Amazon Linux AMI which installs amazon's own flavor of CentOS. Once the instance is up, you will not be able to install a different OS on it. You will have to terminate your existing instance and spin up a new EC2 instance with the AMI that you want.

That being said, you can also use a tool such as Docker https://www.docker.com/. This allows you to spin up docker containers. Each docker container acts like a VM and will allow you to spin up multiple different docker containers with whatever OS you want within your single EC2 instance.

Comment: Thank you for your response sir. Yes. I am already using Docker and Docker compose to deploy my microservice. But I am totally confused because of my little bit discussion related to my project, Since they recommending Kubernetes by launching with multiple clusters. I am not fluent in kubernetes. So confused on 'VM' term in discussion. Also cluster deployment in kubernetes with Master , Pod .Is this VM term related to kubernetes also for deployment in pod ?